# sent an email with express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send an email with Node.js gift I used the module Express-mailer but its not working

```
app.post('/mail', function(req, res, next){
    mailer.extend(app,{
    from: req.body.email,
    host:'smtp.gmail.com',
    secureConnection: true,
    port: 465,
    transportMethod: 'SMTP',
     auth: {
         user: 'example@gmail.com',
         pass: '**********'
     }

  });
       app.mailler.send('email',{
       to: 'test@hotmail.com',
       subject: req.body.subject,
       message: req.body.message

  }, function(err){
    if(err){
       console.log('error');return
    }
     res.send('email sent');
 });
});
```

**error:**

TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined at C:\Users\Developpement\mailer\index.js:49:15 at callbacks (C:\Users\Developpement\mailer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37) at param (C:\Users\Developpement\mailer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11) at pass

Comment: `app.mailler` looks like a typo to me.  What's line 49 in your source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.mailler.send` should be `app.mailer.send`.

**Update**

To fix the second error, "Error: Application already has been extended with Express-Mailer", you have to move your `mailer.extend()` block out of the route and into the parent scope, where it will only be executed once (and mutate your app object only once).

Comment: thank you but still it shows "error" in the console after it displays this message                                                  Error: Application already has been extended with Express-Mailer!

Comment: Then you should only extend it once in one place, such as in a middleware function before your routes.